# Javascript not loaded when ajax content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue that is relative with dynamically loaded content, having a sidebar which has links and loads pages in this way; the problem is relative that javascript is not working when pages are loaded, I used `$document(ready)` for this target but it is not working at all, any hint for this?

Comment: You need to show the code, and give a bit more coherent description of the problem.

Comment: Are you saying the Javascript itself is loaded via Ajax?

Comment: Do you load yr content using jQuery.load() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you're binding events in this way...

```
$('a').click(function () {});
```

And the expecting this event to fire when an anchor is clicked within the dynamic content?

Try binding the event to an element that doesn't change when a page is loaded in eg.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function () {});
```

What happens is that the event is actually bound to the body, when the click event fires on the anchor it bubbles up to the body which then delegates it back to the anchor

Comment: That's what I looking for! Works like a charm! So there's no way to bind events to content that are not load in a dynamic content, right? Just bind to elements like body that doesn't change, good answer after all!